Let's edit away "this sentence" from titles
Examples of "this sentence" in titles:

Help in this sentence
Is this sentence ambiguous?
What does this sentence mean
Does this sentence sound awkward?
Help me translate this sentence

Useless titles.
(A more general issue was raised in Please use specific titles. Don't just ask “Is this grammatically correct?” on English Language Learners Meta.)
Searching for title:"this sentence" is:question gives 172 166 155 138 129 111 98 83 70 57 47 hits.  With almost no exceptions, those questions would benefit from having their title edited.

I'm studying [XYZ], therefore I should look at a question entitled Is this sentence grammatically correct?

... thought no one ever.

In most cases this can easily be fixed by replacing "this sentence" with the actual sentence!

In some cases it's too long, where we can add the relevant part with ellipses.  [It seems ellipses at the end of a title are auto-deleted.]


Why do this?
An example I just edited:

Before:  地 in this sentence
After:  Why is 地 in 慢慢地走?

It's a small change, but it makes a big difference.  A perfectly reasonable question was hidden behind a poor title.
Now, if someone else wants to know why it's 地 in 慢慢地走, they can find the answer.  (Or we can identify a duplicate more easily.)
Let's edit away "this sentence" from titles
I suggest limiting it to a few edits per day (maybe 5), so as to not flood the front page.  Around Sundays the site is a bit quiet, so it's not so unreasonable to do a few more then (being careful not to knock someone's unanswered question off the front page).
I can do it myself, but I'd be happy if others joined in.
It'll probably take a month or two to get this done.  After that, it'd be best that everyone is aware so they don't come back.
